# Type trait for enum member value

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits

I have a type trait to check whether or not the `enum class` contains a member called `None`.

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
    struct has_none : std::false_type
    {
    };

template<typename T>
struct has_none<T,
    std::void_t<decltype(T::None)>> : std::true_type {};
```

This check will be coupled with the `std::is_enum_v`. The question is, how would I create a `type_trait` which would check that the `Enum::None` has value of `0`? Is it even possible when talking about `type_traits`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `std::enable_if`:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_none : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_none<T, std::enable_if_t<T::None == T(0)>> : std::true_type {};
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `conditional_t` to select `true_type`/`false_type` as base class depending on the condition is true or not:

```
template<class E>
constexpr auto EnumToInt(E e) {
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(e);
}
enum class Foo {
    None = 0
};
enum class Bar {
    None = 1
};
template<class T>
struct NoneAs0 : std::conditional_t< EnumToInt(T::None) == 0,
    std::true_type, std::false_type>
{};

int main() {
    std::cout << NoneAs0<Foo>::value << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << NoneAs0<Bar>::value << std::endl; // 0
```

Comment: Not sure if intended, but it doesn't work if the enum doesn't have a `None` constant at all.